# When is the $B$ defined through $\forall i:a_i=v_i\times B$ existent and unique?

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, cross-product

Of course the motivation is to understand what data is needed to define the (electric and) magnetic field through the lorentz force. So suppose we are given $a_1,\ldots,a_n,v_1,\ldots,v_n\in\mathbb R^3$ and we want to verify the existence and uniqueness of a $B\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $\forall i:a_i=v_i\times B$. If I had to make a guess, then I would say that $B$ exists and is unique if $n=3$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is a basis, but I don't know how to prove this. Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness holds for $n>2$, provided the $v_i$ are distinct and non-zero. Existence is not guaranteed for any $n$ without conditions on the $F_i$ and $v_i$. Namely, if there is such a $B$, then we need $v_i\times F_j+v_j\times F_i=0$*. In fact, this condition will give existence.

*I have just realised I made a mistake. The conditions should be $v_i\cdot F_j+v_j\cdot F_i=0$.

The span of the $v_i$ doesn't need to be 3-dimensional: in fact for $n=2$, there is a unique solution provided the conditions hold. We can choose a basis in which $v_1=(1,0,0)^t$, $v_2=(0,1,0)^t$. Then the conditions $v_i\cdot F_j+v_j\cdot F_i=0$ mean that the two forces take the form $F_1=(0,a,b)^t$, $F_2=(-a,0,c)^t$. Then the equations $F_i=v_i\times B$ read

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
a\\
b
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\times 
\begin{pmatrix}
B_1\\
B_2\\
B_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
-B_3\\
B_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-a\\
0\\
c
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\times 
\begin{pmatrix}
B_1\\
B_2\\
B_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
B_3\\
0\\
-B_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, we get the unique solution $B=(-c,b,-a)^t$.

Comment: "provided the vi are distinct and non-zero" - What exactly does distinct mean, should the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be 3-dimensional?

Comment: Distinct means that no two of them are equal.

Comment: You have been more helpful than you can imagine (long story), thank you very much!